# Doubt: $\prod_{b=1}^n(1+\zeta^{ab})=2.$ [Putnam 2015 A3]

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math, roots-of-unity

> Compute $$\log_2\left(\prod_{a=1}^{2015}\prod_{b=1}^{2015}\left(1+e^{2\pi iab/2015}\right)\right)$$ Here $i$ is the imaginary unit (that is, $i^2=-1$).

Can someone explain me this line from the first solution [by Kent merrifield]  posted here

( https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1171025p5624333) :

> If $a$ is relatively prime to $n$, then the numbers $\zeta^{ab}$ for $1\le b\le n$ encompass all $n$ of possible powers of $\zeta,$ and hence $\prod_{b=1}^n(1+\zeta^{b})=2.$

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense unless we know the value of $\zeta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be assuming $n$ is odd, and $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$-th root of $1$.
Then $\zeta^a$ is also a primitive $n$-root of $1$. We have a factorisation
$$X^n-1=\prod_{b=0}^{n-1}(X-\zeta^{ab}).$$
Setting $X=-1$ gives
$$-2=\prod_{b=0}^{n-1}(-1-\zeta^{ab})=(-1)^n\prod_{b=0}^{n-1}(1+\zeta^{ab}).$$

Comment: Why are we assuming n to be odd ?
PS: I am quite new to roots of unity ( just learned it 2 days back )

Comment: If it were even, and you put $X=1$ in $X^n-1$, what do you get?

Comment: well, X^n- 1 will still be 0 ..

Comment: Shouldn't the product go from $b=0$ to $n-1$?

Comment: @Peanut , yes .. anyways thankyou so much , when n is even we  we get LHS -2 and and RHS 0 ..., Right ?